# How to get values from the Cloned TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a Questionnaire like input form where I am asking the question of peoples favourite game consoles and games (as you can see from the code below) all this is in an outer div called duplicator. When I click the 'gamebut' button this calls the Jquery method duplicate() which clones that div so now there will be two divs, similar divs with the smilar textboxes in them. Because its being cloned I am unable to get the data out of it, it only gives me the data for the 1st(orginal) div. How can I get the values from the cloned div, any Suggestions?

**MARKUP:**

```
<div id="duplicator">
<div id="gamesborder">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Consoles</td>
        <td>Games</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>                         
         <%=Html.TextBox("Consoles", ViewData["Consoles"] ?? "") %>
        </td>
        <td><%=Html.TextBox("Games", ViewData["Games"] ?? "") %>                </td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</div>
</div>

<button id="gamebut" type="button" onclick="duplicate()">Add new entry</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
  document.getElementById('gamebut').onclick = duplicate;

  var i = 0;
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicator');

  function duplicate() {
      var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
      clone.id = "duplicator" + ++i;
      original.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  }
```

**Controller Class:**

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Game(string consoles, string games)
{
    ViewData["Consoles"] = consoles;
    ViewData["Games"] = games;
    ViewData["Forename"] = forename;

    if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use classes and then iterate through them, so instead of accessing objects with their ID you use the jquery class selector aka

```
$(".CLASS_NAME");
```

make your input have a class and select via that class

lets say your input has

```
class="duplicated_input"
```

then you select and iterate like this.

```
var _inputs = $(".duplicated_input");

for(var i = 0; i < _inputs.length; i++)
{
    var _input = _inputs[i];
    //do your logic here.

}
```

[example JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/bx54L/)

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail or give me an example with my variable names please, as I am really new to JQuery

Comment: Okay, so I beefed up the JSFiddle, you should be able to see what's going on. If not... I'm sorry but I don't really have the time to explain basic JQuery to you :(